# Getting primary key value from resultset by using Java variable with SQL WHERE clause

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, resultset

I know its not great practise at all to use techniques like this as it is prone to SQL injections, but for speed and testing this is currently how I am doing it. I am creating a program which saves a username, ip and a database name to another database. However when I try and perform a statement like so:

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT LoginID, IPAddress FROM slavelogins WHERE IPAddress = '" + inputString + "';");
            String ClientID = String.valueOf(rs.getInt(1));
            System.out.println("Client ID: " + ClientID);
        } catch (SQLException err) {
            System.err.println("Error retrieving client id, please continue later!" + err);
            System.exit(0);
```

I then run into an error which says the value is before the start of resultset, I believe this means there is no data retrieved from the database, is there a way to fix this or a way around this or an easier way which I am not realising?

P.S LoginID is a primary key if that creates any problems.

The code above retrieves the loginid and displays it to the user as 'ClientID: ' + rs.getInt(1) where rs.getInt should be the loginID.

I have also seen posts about using placeholders in preparedstatements but I haven't seen anything regarding a select query in a normal statement.

The error message:

> Error retrieving client id, please continue later! java.sql.SQLException: Before start of result set

Comment: please edit your question and add the complete error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can think of the `ResultSet` as a cursor over the rows you've queried. Whatever its position may be, you can use [`next()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next--) to check if there's another row there, and move the cursor to it.

The first row of the result is no different - a `ResultSet` start **before the first row**, and you need to use `next()` to move to that row:

```java
if (rs.next()) {
    String clientID = String.valueOf(rs.getInt(1));
    System.out.println("Client ID: " + clientID);
} else {
    System.out.println("No such client");
}
```

Comment: I tried this just there, it then returns an error saying: 'java.sql.SQLException: After end of result set'

Comment: Sorry, i accidentally added an extra rs.next() below the start of the if statement, works perfectly now! thank you